# Group by Hour for Epoch time

Tags: sql, oracle, epoch

I need to group by Hour for converted epoch time, here is what I have done but it is still grouping by the day. Can anyone support?

```
 select count (*) as "Total",to_char(trunc(to_date('19700101 00', 'YYYYMMDD HH24') + ( 1 / 24 / 60 / 60 ) * INSERTION_TIME),'DD/MM/YYYY HH24') as "Day"
from Records
where ID=35 and (INSERTION_TIME/86400)+ to_date('01-01-1970 00:00:00','dd-mm-yyyy HH24:MI:SS') >=sysdate - 4
group by trunc(to_date('19700101 00', 'YYYYMMDD HH24') + ( 1 / 24 / 60 / 60 ) * INSERTION_TIME)
order by trunc(to_date('19700101 00', 'YYYYMMDD HH24') + ( 1 / 24 / 60 / 60 ) * INSERTION_TIME)
```

Comment: Posibbly more safe would be to first convert the *epoch* column to Oracle `DATE` and *than* group by hour.

Comment: Remove the extra `trunc`, which removes that hour component.  You can see this by looking at the ungrouped expressions before trying to use `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get rid of most of the arithmetic and just use:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) as "Total",
       TO_CHAR(
         TRUNC(DATE '1970-01-01' + INTERVAL '1' SECOND * INSERTION_TIME, 'HH'),
         'DD/MM/YYYY HH24'
       ) as "Day"
FROM   Records
WHERE  ID=35
AND    DATE '1970-01-01' + INTERVAL '1' SECOND * INSERTION_TIME >=sysdate - 4
GROUP BY
       TRUNC(DATE '1970-01-01' + INTERVAL '1' SECOND * INSERTION_TIME, 'HH')
ORDER BY
       TRUNC(DATE '1970-01-01' + INTERVAL '1' SECOND * INSERTION_TIME, 'HH')
```

*Note: Epoch time is usually 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC. If your session time zone is not UTC then you may be calculating the epoch time incorrectly and would want to use timestamps instead:*

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) as "Total",
       TO_CHAR(
         TRUNC(
           TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' + INTERVAL '1' SECOND * INSERTION_TIME,
           'HH'
         ),
         'DD/MM/YYYY HH24'
       ) as "Day"
FROM   Records
WHERE  ID=35
AND    TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' + INTERVAL '1' SECOND * INSERTION_TIME
         >=SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '4' DAY
GROUP BY
       TRUNC(
         TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' + INTERVAL '1' SECOND * INSERTION_TIME,
         'HH'
       )
ORDER BY
       TRUNC(
         TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' + INTERVAL '1' SECOND * INSERTION_TIME,
         'HH'
       )
```

Comment: `SYSDATE` is returned in database server operating system time zone, thus "*If your session time zone is not UTC then...*" should be "*If your database server operating system time zone is not UTC then...*"

Answer (score 1):

Notice the behavior of `trunc` on your expression.  It removes the hour component.

**Test case with dbfiddle.uk:**

[Test case](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=36a52701ad2019bf590acf995fad4253)

**The ungrouped SQL, with extra expression in select list:**

```
select to_char(trunc(to_date('19700101 00', 'YYYYMMDD HH24') + ( 1 / 24 / 60 / 60 ) * INSERTION_TIME),'DD/MM/YYYY HH24') as "Day"
     , to_char(     (to_date('19700101 00', 'YYYYMMDD HH24') + ( 1 / 24 / 60 / 60 ) * INSERTION_TIME),'DD/MM/YYYY HH24') as "Day"
  from Records
 where ID = 35 and (INSERTION_TIME/86400) + to_date('01-01-1970 00:00:00','dd-mm-yyyy HH24:MI:SS') >= sysdate - 4
   AND rownum < 6
 order by      (to_date('19700101 00', 'YYYYMMDD HH24') + ( 1 / 24 / 60 / 60 ) * INSERTION_TIME)
;
```

**The ungrouped result:**

[image]

**Now add the `GROUP BY`:**

```
select COUNT(*) AS n
     , to_char(trunc(to_date('19700101 00', 'YYYYMMDD HH24') + ( 1 / 24 / 60 / 60 ) * INSERTION_TIME),'DD/MM/YYYY HH24') as "Day"
     , to_char(     (to_date('19700101 00', 'YYYYMMDD HH24') + ( 1 / 24 / 60 / 60 ) * INSERTION_TIME),'DD/MM/YYYY HH24') as "Day"
  from Records
 where ID = 35 and (INSERTION_TIME/86400) + to_date('01-01-1970 00:00:00','dd-mm-yyyy HH24:MI:SS') >= sysdate - 4
 group by      (to_date('19700101 00', 'YYYYMMDD HH24') + ( 1 / 24 / 60 / 60 ) * INSERTION_TIME)
 order by      (to_date('19700101 00', 'YYYYMMDD HH24') + ( 1 / 24 / 60 / 60 ) * INSERTION_TIME)
;
```

**The grouped result:**

[image]

**To create a test case:**

```
CREATE TABLE Records (
    id              int
  , insertion_time  int
);

INSERT INTO Records VALUES (35, 4011134567);
INSERT INTO Records VALUES (35, 4011134567);
INSERT INTO Records VALUES (35, 4011134567);
INSERT INTO Records VALUES (35, 4011134567);
```

Comment: Thanks for your clarification; however, when I did this, it returns the records with grouping also with minutes and seconds like below:
`3 03/10/2021 12
2 03/10/2021 12
3 03/10/2021 12
7 03/10/2021 12`

Comment: @AhmedZein Show your test case.  I've added a test case to my answer.  As you can see, it behaves as expected.  Every question, with this kind of issue, should include a minimal test case, in a form which can be directly used by the readers.

Comment: @AhmedZein I don't see any minutes or seconds in your output.  There's a `count` `N` and the `date hour` result, followed by additional rows of the same.  Show the exact SQL you used.

Comment: @AhmedZein I've added the fiddle link to the very top of the answer you can use for testing.

Comment: Hi @Jon Armstrong
I used the one you provided, Yes it doesn't show hours or minutes but the hour "12" is repeated and not grouped that's what I mean. I need all records 3 + 2 + 3 + 7 to be grouped in one record with hour "12".

Comment: @AhmedZein One of the queries shows the `UNGROUPED` result on purpose, for review.  Try the other one.... AND PLEASE, show your exact test case and result.  It's tough to guess what you missed if you aren't showing your work.  Feel free to update the fiddle and post the updated `URL` here, for review.